# Regex group rearrangement

Tags: regex, regex-group

I think my approach itself is wrong in terms of matching groups. Is it possible to do something clever?

My expression is:

```
<Record><((\w*)\s+((value="(.*?)")|(utcdate="(.*?)")).*?)></Record>
```

Here is the link: [regexr](http://regexr.com/5b9aj)

My input is:

```
<StepVal Name="Something"><Record><Time value="2.001" unit="s" /></Record></StepVal>
<StepVal Name="Something"><Record><Date utcdate="07/08/2015 04:40:14" timezone="UTC" /></Record></StepVal>
```

And expected output is:

```
<StepVal Name="Something"><Record type="Time" value="2.001"/></StepVal>
<StepVal Name="Something"><Record type="Date" value="07/08/2015 04:40:14"/></StepVal>
```

As you can see in the screenshot, the replace expression works in first case with 2nd and 5th group.
[image]

And for second case I have to use 2nd and 7th group.
[image]

I think I have tied myself in a knot here.
Is there a better approach other than groups?

And I apolgise in advance for using regex to untie an xml. I have to deal with the cards I have been handed.

Comment: Your question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need two group:

1. Group1: type of record
2. Group2: value of record

You could try following regex.

```
<Record><(\w*)\s+(?:value="|utcdate=")(.*?)".*?><\/Record>
```

Details:

- `(\w*)`: Group1 - type of record
- `(?:value="|utcdate=")`: Non-capturing group - matches value=" or utcdate="
- `(.*?)`: Group2 - value of record

I verified the result in https://regexr.com/5b9c9

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it works. I will test it out with some more cases before accepting it as answer. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems.